# X11 : How to Render Continuously

Tags: c++, c, x11

I am creating an X11 window for a game, but it seems to only do the expose event once in a while (like maximizing and resizing), is there any way to have X11 call expose constantly? Kind of how glut has glutPostRedisplay()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expose event just tells you that a part of the window which was previously obscured is now visible, so you might need to redraw. There is no restriction that you redraw *only* at expose events.

Comment: Oh okay, cool. So I can probably just put my render logic inside the while(alive) loop if I want to render continuously?

Comment: In principle yes. However if you are updating a lot, you might want to synchronize with vertical sync (I don't know how to do that in X, though).